# Bug with tag selection when featured question selected

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

today I face this page: 
[image: tag search features tab bug]

If you look carefully you will not see the featured question tab on this screen, and it just make me click back and reclick on the link I used and same error...

Step to reproduce :

- Click on Unix & Linux logo
- select `featured` questions
- click on `/tags`link to see the list of tags
- click on almost any tag (one for which there is no features question )
- see the strange screen.

Nothing to bad but still not really consistent with the rest of the website experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This view is for featured questions with the wanted tag.

When there are none, this is what you see.

There was a recent change to the phrasing on the sidebar, just under the number of questions (0) - it now says: `0 featured questions tagged <tag name>`.

Comment: It does seems that the behavior just change because I don't issue the problem anymore. Now it does display question related to this tag and not that strange message. what was strange is the fact the message told you are under an non existing tab